# can not find table for join in asp core identity core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

i have 3 table in identitycore 2 in aspcore for `Users` , `Roles` and `UserRole` .

[image: Tabels Image]

so i need to fill `UserRoleViewModel` with all field of 3 tables .

i used this code for join of tabels :

```
   public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<User>,
        IApplicationUserManager
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
_passwordValidators;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _services;
        private readonly DbSet<User> _users;
        private readonly DbSet<Role> _roles;
        private readonly DbSet<UserRole> _userRoles;
        private readonly IApplicationUserStore _userStore;

            IUnitOfWork uow,
            IUsedPasswordsService usedPasswordsService)
            : base((UserStore<User, Role, ApplicationDbContexct, int, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, UserToken, RoleClaim>)storer)
        {

            _users = uow.Set<User>();
            _roles = uow.Set<Role>();
            _userRoles = uow.Set<UserRole>();
        }

 public List<UserRoleViewModel> FindUserRole()
        {
            var userinfo=from users in Users 
                         join userRole in _userRoles on  users
        }
```

but when i need to for exmaple `user.id` it not show me property of user tabel . this problem have for all tables .

**how can i join this tabels ?**

Comment: Relations are configures at the context level. `User` should have a `Roles` collection. You shouldn't need to perform any joins at all. Why don't you use the *default* Identity model anyway?

Comment: you say i must add dbcontext in class ?

Comment: You can use the default identity template . and use var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(UserId);
            _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user); to get the assigned roles .

Comment: @NanYu thanks . it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I using this code for return all info about users and they role :

```
    [HttpGet("UserList")]
    public IEnumerable<User> UserList()
    {
        return _applicationUserManager.Users.ToList();

    }
 [HttpGet("Roles")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Role()
    {
        List<UserRoleViewModel> URVM = new List<UserRoleViewModel>();
        foreach (var item in UserList())
        {
            var users = await _applicationUserManager.FindUserById(item.Id);
            var roles = await _applicationUserManager.GetRolesAsync(users);
            var roleName = await _applicationRoleManager.FindRoleByNameList(roles[0]);
            URVM.Add(new UserRoleViewModel
            {
                Id = users.Id,
                Email = users.Email,
                BirthDate = users.BirthDate,
                CreatedDateTime = users.CreatedDateTime,
                FirstName = users.FirstName,
                IsActive = users.IsActive,
                PhoneNmuberConfirmed=users.PhoneNumberConfirmed,
                IsEmailPublic = users.IsEmailPublic,
                LastName = users.LastName,
                TwoFactorEnabled = users.TwoFactorEnabled,
                EmailConfirmed = users.EmailConfirmed,
                LockoutEnabled = users.LockoutEnabled,
                LastVisitDateTime = users.LastVisitDateTime,
                Location = users.Location,
                PhotoFileName = users.PhotoFileName,
                RoleLevel = roleName.RoleLevel,
                Description = roleName.Description,
                roleId = roleName.Id
            });
        }
        return Ok(URVM);
    }
```